# MT4J set gravity at center of MTComponent

Tags: mt4j

I want to develop a application using MT4J.
Scenario that I want to implement is like

1. multiple balls on screen.
2. balls can be placed any where using touch.

above points implemented now most important point that I have faced 
3. gravity is at center of container so balls attracted toward center.

Please help me out how could I implement center of gravity ? So that ball attracted towards center.

Hope you understand what I want to know If you don not get me please let know I will share more details.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. The first thing I would recommend is that you check out the example "Physics Playground" application that comes with MT4j. This will show you how to assign physical bodies to components, and how to set up a physics simulation engine with jBox2d. But I have a feeling that you have already done that, I just wanted to be sure :)

So, back to your question. You shouldn't think about your problem in terms of gravity but rather joints. Joints allow one component to affect the physical behavior of another component, and that's what you are looking for. So try creating an invisible, static, non-collide-able component in the center of your container, and then add (and remove) joints from this component with your balls that are moving around the screen.

Specifically, check out distance joints in the Box2d manual (http://box2d.org/manual.pdf , Section 8.5). You want to create a distance joint that has a distance of 0, and then play around with the dampening ratio and frequency to get the behavior you are looking for.

Also, if jBox2d is giving you problems, consider upgrading to the newest version. It might require that you do a little debugging in the mt4j source code to get it working, but it can be definitely worth it to have a more stable physics engine, more features, and up-to-date documentation which actually corresponds to the code.